# JApplet fails to run in HTML page

Tags: java, html, netbeans, jung, japplet

I have created a JApplet using the JUNG library in Netbeans that compiles and runs normally. However, when I try to create an html file that runs the applet, only a grey pane appears but the components are missing. 
My class is :

```
   public class View extends JApplet {

   //Here I declare the buttons etc..

   public View()
{
    initializeComponent();
            fetchGraphs();

}


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    f = new JFrame();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    x = screenSize.width;
    y = screenSize.height;


    f.getContentPane().add(new View());
    f.setTitle("Social Network Privacy Settings and Access Control");
    f.setLocation(new Point(15, 20));
    f.setSize(new Dimension(x-20,y-50));
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setResizable(false);

    f.setVisible(true);
}  
}
```

The method  initializeComponent() adds all the components to the main window. I used JFrameBuilder to build some basic components. JFrameBuilder uses a method addComponent(container, component, x, y, width, height) to add components

I use the code below for that:

```
  contentPane = (JPanel)this.getContentPane();

  //to create the japplet contentpane

  addComponent(contentPane, genGraphButton, (int)(0.35*x),(int)(0.63*y),       
  (int)(0.2*x),28);

  // to add components
```

Then I create an html file:

```
    <applet code = 'MyPackage.View' 
    archive = 'MyProject.jar',
    width = 1600, 
    height = 800/>
```

in the /dist folder but then only a grey pane appears when I try to open it with Mozilla Firefox. The strange thing is that I have created another simple applet, this time with netbeans JBuilder and it runs normally in a web page.

I really need some help!

Comment: *"Then I create an html file:"*  Please post the entire (short - with only the applet element - no text & rubbish) HTML being used.  Also go to the Java Control Panel and ensure the console is set to pop up for applets.  There is probably a lot of useful information in it.  Copy/paste any data you see in the console.

Comment: <applet code = 'MyPackage.View' 
        archive = 'MyProject.jar', 
        width = 1600, 
        height = 800 />

Comment: I just noticed *""Social Network Privacy Settings and Access Control"* & doubt this will end well, especially for a sand-boxed applet.  What does the applet actually do?

Comment: I'm developing a visualization tool that shows privacy and access control in Facebook-style SNS with respect to the Social Graph. I will not use any SN API, just JUNG to demonstrate with a mockup graph how these settings work.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the advice but I haven't yet managed to create the html file. I still get a gray box without any component inside. I don't really know what else to do. Any other suggestions? Maybe someone has to check my entire code. I believe it is an error caused by the way I add components (JFrame, contentPane or layouts) and not an HTML error

Comment: *"Any other suggestions? "* How about  **Stop ignoring advice!**  Create proper HTML, rather than that rubbish currently used.  & What is in the Java Console?  I need *information,* I cannot debug this using *magic.*

Comment: Ok I created an html file like this: <html>
<body>
<applet 
    code='thesis.View' 
    archive='Thesis.jar,jung-algorithms-2.0.1.jar,collections-generic-4.01.jar,jung-graph-impl-2.0.1.jar,jung-visualization-2.0.1.jar'
    alt='Java is DISABLED in this browser!'
    width='1600'
    height='800'>
This browser does not recognize the applet element! 
</applet>
</body>
</html>                           What do you mean with Java Console? I get no errors there.

Comment: *"What do you mean with Java Console? I get no errors there."*  I expected you'd see some.  Does the code have any `try/catch` blocks?

Comment: No. As I said the code runs perfect in Netbeans and the JApplet apears without any errors. And something else. I also tried to make it a jnlp file something that is automated in netbeans. But again I get a blank gray window.

Comment: *"the code runs perfect in Netbeans"*  I never asked & don't care if it runs in your IDE.  I don't provide support for IDEs.  It seems the **problem** here is when running in a web page.  So concentrate on that & forget the 'automagic' IDE.

Comment: Ok, but I wonder why the simple applet that I created (again included Jung) ran normally in a web browser. I used the same html code (without jung jars sine they are included in the main jar file). And I used the same method. I created a JFrame in my main class and I added the JApplet on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the JUNG library, it relies on the two third party libraries, Collections-Generic & Cern Colt Scientific Library 1.2.0.  As mentioned by @othman they need to be added to the run-time class-path of the applet (added to the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element).

But just so we are clear, make sure the HTML contains more than just the applet element.  Something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet 
    code='MyPackage.View' 
    archive='MyProject.jar,jung.jar,collections.jar,colt-scientific.jar'
    alt='Java is DISABLED in this browser!'
    width='1600'
    height='800'>
This browser does not recognize the applet element! 
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, you'll need to change the names of the last 3 Jars to their real names.

Comment: no it is just an aplication similar but much better than netbeans JBuilder. Iy is seperate from my code. I just used it to create some compnents and get some generated code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Applet expert, since I don't use them, but IIRC you need the `init()` method to initialize your view. `main(...)` is not called for an applet.

Comment: His appplet's main just creates frame that allows running it as an application. Main does not bother applet to run. The UI is created into the applet's constructor. His problem is in HTML

Comment: I used exactly the same html code for the simple applet and run successfully. Moreover, the web page seems to load the applet and a grey pane equal to the coordinates I give. The problem is that the components inside do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure that new lines you added into the html are legal. I mean write `<applet` and `/>` without any new lines and spaces.

Second, test that your jar is really available. To do this go to the same URL that you go to retrieve your HTML without HTML but with jar, i.e.

if your HTML URL is: http://somehost/my.html type in browser http://somehost/MyProject.jar and see that you can download the jar.

if this works check the `code` attribute. Is your package name really MyPackage? Capitalized? Do you know it is not according the naming convention?

Also check java console. Find it somewhere in menus of your browser: it depends in browser. I believe that you will see the reason there in form of exception stack trace.

Comment: *"I am not sure that new lines you added into the html are legal."*  The HTML as shown is utterly invalid.  Besides your tip, `applet` attributes are not followed by commas. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference also the JUG jars in your applet tag :

<

```
applet code = 'MyPackage.View' 

archive = 'MyProject.jar , jung_xx.jar',

width = 1600, 

height = 800 /
>
```

in the archive attribute add all jung jars that you have currently in your netbeans project classpath.