# JApplet works in applet viewer, not in HTML page

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, jung, japplet

This topic has been covered in one form or another but none of the other threads have been able to help.  My issue is very similar to this post, I am making a JUNG graph with added functionality, but none of the solutions helped:

[JApplet fails to run in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761271/japplet-to-html-problem)

I had a Java application that I converted to a JApplet.  The JApplet works fine in the applet viewer in Eclipse but will not work when I try to open it in a webpage (I have tried IE, FireFox, and Chrome).  I have my HTML page and archive folder both in the same directory.  When I load the HTML page it just brings up nothing.

Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<title>Applet</title>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<applet code="prerna.blueprint.main.BPTester.class" 
        archive="applet1.jar"
        width="800" height="800">
</applet>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to have code="BPTester.class" it gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BPTester.class but when I use code="prerna.blueprint.main.BPTester.class" it gives me no errors just nothing happens. (prerna/blueprint/main/BPTester.class is the file path in my src folder).  I exported my Java project as a runnable jar file, is this correct?  I created a simple JApplet that worked fine when I did all the same steps but it won't work for BPTester.class.

If I need to post my BPTester.class code I can.

I don't understand why I can't view the JApplet in a webpage, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it worked for the simple applet but not for the more complex one, then the problem is likely in the applet code itself. Have you checked the browser's java console for error messages? Are you trying to access resources as files?

Comment: Is the jar in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: I figured it might be in the code, just didn't understand why the applet viewer worked but not the webpage.  When I run it through Tomcat it always gives me a ClassNotFoundException, why can't it find the class? 

The code consists of multiple classes ranging from 50 to over 1000 of code.

I am creating a graph visualization using the JUNG library, tried with the suggested jar files, still no success.  I'll look into JWS.

Comment: Yes all files are in the same directory.

Comment: 1) Please start comments to me with @UserName or similar, so I am notified. 2)  I thought it should have been obvious from both the linked thread and my inquiry, that the **JUNG API NEEDS TO BE ON THE RUN-TIME CLASS-PATH** (Sheesh!) 3) Does the code ignore exceptions?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added the JUNG API to the class path and even added the colt and collections jars to the class path.  Still am getting nothing.

Comment: You'll have to reference those jars in the archive parameter. But, if your code needs to be signed then all of the jars will have to be signed. Alternatively, combine all the jars together in one and sign that one jar. You can use a tool like yguard to combine the jars. It can obfuscate and shrink too but you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ended up working for me was adding every single jar I used in the japplet to the HTML archive tag then had to sign every jar.  I then had an issue with accessing my database within the applet1.jar so I just put an absolute path for its location.

Answer (score 1):

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)

The applet needs to be digitally signed (by you) and trusted (by the end user, when prompted) before it can obtain such information.  Given this applet is being deployed using a traditional applet element (i.e. not using web start), ***all*** jars need to be signed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign every jar. You can sign all the jars with the jarsigner utility. Example:

```
jarsigner.exe "nameofthejar.jar" "alias"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove .class from the end. You either use a file path with slashes and .class at the end or you only use periods and no .class at the end.

Try turning on tracing in the java control panel. It will then produce a log file in the following path that may help: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\sun\java\Deployment\log`

Comment: I just tried it with only periods and no .class, and also with slashes and .class.  Nothing happens except a grey square where the japplet should be.  Will try to turn tracing on now.

Comment: I've turned tracing on but nothing is in the log folder

Comment: Make it show the console and then press 5 as soon as the console shows. This will show you detail as it's loading.

Comment: @SarelBrotha I checked the log and got this error:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)

Comment: To read and write files on the local disk you must create a signed applet. Once it is signed your applet will first ask the user to trust the author, then the applet will run with full permissions. Look for a tutorial on signing using jarsigner.